# discountine function if varible becomes not null

Tags: php

Is there a way to have PHP discontinue execution of a class if my error variable (not a PHP error but a error set when input is invalid) is ever set without constantly checking the error variable? like a passive listener? My script has many places a error could occur. Something like this:

```
if(empty($this->error)) $this->error= function1();
if(empty($this->error)) $this->error= function2();
if(empty($this->error)) $this->error= function3();
```

$this->error is always returned a null value unless a error occurs. if it is ever not null I want exit the rest of the function with out having to put if(empty($this->error)) in front of everything.

Edit: farther explanation:
I suppose I want something that automatically checks if $this->error is empty after every line of code, without me telling it to, then exits the function if it's not empty, like a break in a loop.

the suggested posts do not solve my problem as they still require the condition be manually checked. I want something like this:

```
stays_empty($this->error)
{
    $this->error= function1();
    //PHP checks if $this->error is still empty. Continue if it is, break if it's not.
    $this->error= function2();
    //PHP checks if $this->error is still empty. Continue if it is, break if it's not.
    $this->error= function3();
    //PHP checks if $this->error is still empty. Continue if it is, break if it's not.
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Short answer, No. Cannot be done. But the same effect can be achieved by  using a `try` and a `catch` block, throwing an `exception` when there is an error.

Comment: Use Exceptions rather than errors perhaps?

Comment: You could do this by the magic function `__set()`.

Comment: The selected answer here presents an interesting way to achieve much of what I think you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682355/php-detecting-when-a-variables-value-has-been-changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Detecting when a variables value has been changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682355/php-detecting-when-a-variables-value-has-been-changed)

Answer (score 0):

When doing repetitive actions, you should consider using loops instead of repeating code many times.

Many may not know this, but you can actually use variables a function names too as shown in this example.

```
<?php

class Whatever
{
    function __construct() {

        // Names of the functions we wish to run
        $functionNameList = ['function1', 'function2', 'function3'];

        // Looping our function names
        foreach ($functionNameList as $key => $functionName) {
            // Inserting variable as function name
            $this->error = $this->$functionName();
            if ($this->error) {
                echo 'Error found ';
                break; // This would break out of the foreach loop [OR]
                return; // This will break out of the function
            }
        }
    }
    public function function1() {
        echo 1;
        return '';
    }
    public function function2() {
        echo 2;
        return 'error';
    }
    public function function3() {
        echo 3;
        return '';
    }
}
$x = new Whatever();
```

You could also use exceptions as mentioned in other answers, but I'm answering your question in a fashion suitable for any situation with lots of repetition.

Edit: Short Version

```
    $functionNameList = ['function1', 'function2', 'function3'];
    foreach ($functionNameList as $key => $functionName) {
        $this->error = $this->$functionName();
        if ($this->error) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Edit: Super Short Version (Not as clear)

```
    $functionNameList = ['function1', 'function2', 'function3'];
    foreach ($functionNameList as $key => $functionName) {
        if ($this->error = $this->$functionName()) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the long run i believe that just adds more code to the script. My goal is to reduce code. Thank you though

Comment: No problem, it depends on how many times you're calling the functions. If you're calling 20, the six lines would be much shorter and easier to change how it functions than changing each set one at a time.

Check my edit with the short version.